# New C# files are generated with the wrong type

Tags: c#

I am a C# beginner and just started going through the msdn tutorial to create a pictureViewer. However, I noticed that I don't see a Form1.cs file generated as seen in the example tutorial. Instead I see a Form1.h file which contains all the code that the tutorial explains to be in the Form1.cs file. Is there any setting by which I can control whether Form1.h or Form1.cs should get generated from my Form design?

Comment: Are you sure you made a C# project, and not a C or C++ project?

Comment: Yeah, C# does not use .h files. You probably created a C or C++ project be mistake.

Answer (score 5):

The file you have created was a C or C++ file. Delete that project, then create a new project making sure that you choose Visual C# from the options.

New Project -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Windows Forms Application

Select the name and location then click OK :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I created a Visual C++ project instead of a Visual C# project. I have created a Visual C# project now and it looks good now. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck with learning C#, I'm sure you'll love it. Try checking out the ReSharper addon trial. It's a Visual Studio addon that is pretty damn useful for beginners. I'm not sure if it has a free version, but the trial should last long enough to help you get used to the language.